# Как добавить библиотеку в проект WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, библиотеки

я работаю в Visual studio 2019 C# WPF проект. Подскажите пожалуйста максимально пошагово как подключить библиотеку https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader к моему проекту?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала находим вашу библиотеку в Nuget галерее
[image: Сначала находим вашу библиотеку в Nuget галерее]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И устанавливаем
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Готово!

Answer (score 0):

Откройте NuGet Package Manager:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поиск и установка необходимого пакета NuGet:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]