# Не работает MahApps.Metro

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps-metro

System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: "Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "MahApps.Metro, Version=1.6.5.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" либо одну из их зависимостей. Требуется сборка со строгим именем. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x80131044)"

FileLoadException: Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "MahApps.Metro, Version=1.6.5.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" либо одну из их зависимостей. Требуется сборка со строгим именем. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x80131044)

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мой проект был подписан, в то время как MahApps.Metro - нет. В этом и была вся ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

Ну тут доходчиво все объяснено - у вас не хватает сборки MahApps.Metro с версией 1.6.5.1.
 Либо она у вас есть, но другой версии.Можете открыть ваш проект, и найти файл MahApps.Metro.dll. Если его нет, то скорее всего, то скорее всего вы не установили необходимый Nuget. А если же есть, то посмотреть версию этой библиотеки через свойства файла
О том, как добавить нужную вам библиотеку через Nuget написано [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1090529/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-wpf)

Comment: Проблема в том, что она установлена. Даже правильной версии) https://i.imgur.com/8F5ORDX.png